# How do I view the pin numbering scheme in an Altium library?

Tags: altium

I use the *misc* library of Altium, for example the capacitor and resistor symbols and footprints. Later, I need to replace the footprint with my own. How are the pins numbered in the misc library?

How can I open a component from the Altium-integrated *misc* library to verify which pin of the sch library symbol is numbered 1 or 2?

Comment: I have no idea what you just asked....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the .intLib file, altium will allow you to extract the source .pcblib and .schlib files so you can edit / inspect them, the pin numbering should be immediately apparent when you open that footprint in the .pcblib file. Just be sure to only have the .intlib or only have the .schlib/.pcblib pair installed in your active libraries at once. If both are present, altium will prefer the .intlib source in your project and it will drive you mad when you make a change to a footprint and it never pushes to your pcb.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to able to edit/verify/create your components present in the Misc Devices/Connectors library.

Then, you click open. Assuming you didn't change the default directory, go to 
"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Altium\AD16\Library" and you shall find your library here in this folder. 
AD16 is named so because I am using version 16 of Altium, so yours might be different.

Once you've opened the library, you can go to SCH Library or PCB Library to do whatever you want. You can view the pinouts of the components or edit them or add more footprints.

Hope this helps!!